# How to update specific element of array at once in MongoDB + Java?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

original documents :

```json
{
  _id: 'test1',
  arr: [ '111', '222', '333', '333' ]
},
{
  _id: 'test2,
  arr: [ '111', '222', '333' ]
}
```

executed java code :

```java
Bson filter = Filters.and(Filters.exists("arr"), Filters.all("arr", "333"));
Bson bson = Updates.set("arr.$", "999");
UpdateResult result = collection.updateMany(filter, bson);
```

the result I expected (even chatGPT responded like this. so more confused) :

```json
{
  _id: 'test1',
  arr: [ '111', '222', '999', '333' ]
},
{
  _id: 'test2,
  arr: [ '111', '222', '999' ]
}
```

actual result :

```json
{
  _id: 'test1',
  arr: [ '999', '222', '333', '333' ]
},
{
  _id: 'test2,
  arr: [ '999', '222', '333' ]
}
```

1. Since filter is only used to specify documents, it has nothing to do with array elements.
   Therefore, regardless of the filter, the first index of the array is changed.
   -> Do I understand correctly?
2. So arr.$ always points to the 1st index? then, what's different from arr.0?
3. How can I change the element as I expect? of course, reply using mongodb queries instead of java are also welcome.

Many thanks.

Comment: What happens if you change the `.all` to `.eq` (or whatever is syntactically correct for Java)? Do you plan to pass more than one value? I also think the `exists` is redundant

Comment: @user20042973 Since I remove `exists`, it works fine! but I don't understand why result changes.

it's an `and` condition, and it's "redundant", so I don't think it should have any effect whether or not I remove. so confusing..